# how to make sure a button function is executed properly

Tags: android, android-view

I want to make a button that allows to go to a random page, but I am having trouble with the logic of it, as I can see loopholes but I dont know how to solve them. Or should i use a different approach? Code as below.

```
qn3_nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
                    int rng = new Random().nextInt(2) + 1;
                    if (rng == i && !qns.contains(1)) {
                        qns.add(1);
                        Intent qn1 = new Intent(question3.this, question1.class);
                        qn1.putExtra("name", name);
                        qn1.putIntegerArrayListExtra("questions", qns);
                        startActivity(qn1);
                    } else if (rng == i && !qns.contains(2)) {
                        qns.add(2);
                        Intent qn2 = new Intent(question3.this, question2.class);
                        qn2.putExtra("name", name);
                        qn2.putIntegerArrayListExtra("questions", qns);
                        startActivity(qn2);
                    } else if (rng == i && !qns.contains(3)) {
                        qns.add(3);
                        Intent qn3 = new Intent(question3.this, question3.class);
                        qn3.putExtra("name", name);
                        qn3.putIntegerArrayListExtra("questions", qns);
                        startActivity(qn3);
                    }
                }
        }
    });
```

loopshole that is... the user will need to press the button multiple times if the function does not meet the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add your Intents into an `ArrayList<Intent>`:

```
ArrayList<Intent> pages = new ArrayList();
pages.add(qn1);
pages.add(qn2);
pages.add(qn3);
```

After that generate a random `int` between 0 and the `list.size()` inside the `onClick` and `get` that page from the list:

```
int index = new Random().nextInt(pages.size());
Intent page = pages.get(index);
startActivity(page);
```

Finally remove that page from the list by calling:

```
pages.remove(index);
```

Just don't forget to check if the `ArrayList` is empty or not in the first line of the `onClick`:

```
if(pages.size == 0) return;
```

I hope it works!

Comment: how do i pass this intent arraylist to the next page?

Comment: You can not pass `ArrayList` of `Intents` instead you can create a list of possible indexes and pass it through your activities, and then select and remove an index from that list

Comment: is it possible for me to convert a string into a class name? for example i generated number 1, it needs to lead me to qn1 so i make a string "question" + number, in the intent i put Intent qn1 = new Intent(context, string.class); ?

Comment: you can convert it into an string name by calling `YourClass.class.getSimpleName()` and then use a switch to convert it to a class again